# How do I fix my http error while using spotipy to retrieve track information using the spotify API

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I am looking to retrieve audio features of a specific track using the spotipy library for the Spotify API. However, I am first trying to see if I can use spotipy to get some information. But when I copy the literal code of the spotipy documentation, it does not work. It geves the error: HTTP Error for GET to HTTP Error for GET to https://api.spotify.com/v1/search with Params: {'q': 'year:2018', 'limit': 50, 'offset': 1000, 'type': 'track', 'market': None} returned 404 due to Not found. or other HTTP errors
This seems strange since I litterly use the code provided in the documentation. I have tried this with several different code and everywhere I get the same error. I must do something wrong but I haven't got a clue what.

This is the code:

```
    import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
cid = 'ID'
secret = 'key'
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=cid, client_secret=secret)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager
=
client_credentials_manager) 

artist_name = []
track_name = []
popularity = []
track_id = []


for i in range(0,10000,50):
    track_results = sp.search(q='year:2018', type='track', limit=50,offset=i)
    for i, t in enumerate(track_results['tracks']['items']):
        artist_name.append(t['artists'][0]['name'])
        track_name.append(t['name'])
        track_id.append(t['id'])
        popularity.append(t['popularity']) 
        
        
track_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'artist_name' : artist_name, 'track_name' : track_name, 'track_id' : track_id, 'popularity' : popularity})
print(track_dataframe.shape)
track_dataframe.head()
```

Comment: If I request 50 tracks with an offset of 950, I don't get an error. When I change the offset to 951, I do get the error you had.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Spotify's API documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/search), the maximum amount of items that can be returned in a search is 1000, that's why 950 is the largest offset that still has results.

[image]